# How to set TextView of another Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I pass data between activities in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

I have two activities. One with text and image views and the other with a button.

I would like to click the button on the activity, go to the second activity and set the text and images of that second activity.

Can anyone give me any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** Use `Intent`.

**2.** For Keeping it simple you can use `PutExtra()` to **send the data to another activity** with the
       intent, and can **get the data on the another activity by using** `getExtras()`

**3.** You can also use `startActivityforResult()` for the **same purpose**.

**/////////////Edited//////////**

**Eg:**

**In Activity Class_One**

```
Intent i = new Intent(Class_One.this , Class_Two.class);
i.putExtra("Name", name);
startActivity(i);
```

**In Activity Class_Two**

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String name = i.getExtras().getString("Name");
```

Comment: I have added an example for you......

Comment: Thanks.

But with the put extra, can it not be set up in such a way where it can be a method?

Comment: You can send the value from Activity A to Activity B, and then get those values and use them as an arguments for calling a method....

Comment: I didnt get u at this...If you are using the value from the String file, then why r you sending the value from one Activity to another

Comment: I would like to use the second activity over and over. With each onclick method on the first activity controlling the textViews on the second activity. The strings contain the text to be used.

Comment: Calling one Activity's method from other, can be done using Composition.